# Fast way to subset from data.frame / data.table based on metadata table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, binary-search

I want to make a subset of my data based on two conditions from my metadata.

```
data= data.frame (w=c(rep ("a", 10),rep("b", 10), rep ("c", 10)), y=(rep(c(1,2,3),10)), v=rnorm (30))
metadata = data.frame (w=c("b","a",),y= c(1,2))

allY <- data.frame ()
mainY <- data.frame ()

for (x in 1:length (data [,1])){
allY <- data.frame (data [which (data$w %in% metadata[x,1]),])
mainY <- data.frame (rbind (mainY, allY [which (allY$y %in% metadata[x,2]),]))
}
mainY
```

The problem is that both data and metadata are quite big and it has been taking hours to do so. And when it finished I had an error:

Do you know how could I seed up the process, maybe using data.table instead?

Many thanks!

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't do anything (`mainY` is empty at the end), making it hard to figure out what you are doing. The selection `metadata[x,2]` almost certainly does not do what you want: `x` is being converted from a factor to a numeric. If it wasn't a factor then it would be using the rownames, of which you have none.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve and show the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have used metadata[,1] instead metadata [x,1] and excluded the for loops and my problem is now solved. It was really quick to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell... but I suspect what you want can be done with simply:

```
merge(data,metadata)
```

Which isn't exactly fast in R, but better than the `for` loop. If you convert to `data.table` beforehand, and set the keys, you can just run `merge` like that, and it will work very fast.

Comment: I have changed the codes, I think now you can get what I mean...I don't think merge will solve my problem since I want to have an table exactly like `data` and the information in `data` and `metadata` are completly different. Many thanks